# I have a large spreadsheet of clients and trying to build a formula that will give me the ability to match client, billing type and update with cost

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: client list with billing type of costs]

This is the list of clients that are similar to what I have. In the first column is the client name, second column is the billing type of when they will be billed and the third thru sixth column I have the total costs of each billing type.

[image: Billing cost information]

If you see the image, I am trying to use this table to create a formula on the third column that will match the client and the billing type and then pull the cost of the matching billing type.

Comment: Try: `=XLOOKUP(H2,$A$2:$A$4,CHOOSECOLS($C$2:$F$4,XMATCH(I2&"*",$C$1:$F$1,2)))` You may need to change the cell reference and ranges.  Or may be this `=XLOOKUP(1,(H2=$A$2:$A$4)*(I2=$B$2:$B$4),INDEX($C$2:$F$4,,XMATCH(I2&"*",$C$1:$F$1,2)))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no Excel Constraints, then you can use the following formulas:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(H2=$A$2:$A$4)*(I2=$B$2:$B$4),INDEX($C$2:$F$4,,XMATCH(I2&"*",$C$1:$F$1,2)))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(H2=$A$2:$A$4)*(I2=$B$2:$B$4),CHOOSECOLS($C$2:$F$4,XMATCH(I2&"*",$C$1:$F$1,2)))
```

---

Or,

Using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> to spill as an array for the whole range of `Billing` in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=MAP(H2:H4,I2:I4,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(1,(x=A2:A4)*(y=B2:B4),CHOOSECOLS(C2:F4,XMATCH(y&"*",C1:F1,2)))))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is sometimes the best solution. See picture for reference:

```
=INDEX(
    D10:G12,
    XMATCH(B3:B5, B10:B12),
    XMATCH(C3:C5, D9:G9)
)
```

[image]